# Angular Ui Router - Set Parent Programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

There's any way of setting the parent in Angular UI Router programmatically? 
Something using the $scope? like

```
 myPage: {
            parent: ($scope) => {
                 return $scope.parentProperty;
            },
            template,
            controller
         }
```

Comment: Some more context would be useful.

Comment: Are you using components?

Comment: I'm using components. 
The context is relatively simple, I have two pages that need use the same component, this component has 3 pages, the parent of these 3 pages should be defined by who is using the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component definition add:

```
bindings: { parentCtrl: '=' }
```

and then where ever you use the component simply add parentCtrl="$ctrl" (or whatever the name of the current controller is.)